# PowerShell not using parameters

Tags: powershell

Why in PowerShell does:

`Get-LocalUser ‘John’` work when I would have expected you need to tell PowerShell the parameter so `Get-LocalUser -Name ‘John’.`

How come PowerShell  ‘knows’

the value ‘John’ should be bound to the Name parameter and not to some other parameter?

I would love to know the technical reason but can’t find it.

Thx a lot!

John

Comment: It's a [positional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters#parameter-position), so the parameter name is optional. `Get-Help Get-LocalUser -Parameter "Name"` shows the details.

Comment: @Jeroen recommend changing your comment into an answer.